# Java "ajp-9009-AsyncTimeout" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space Errors

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I have two Web Projects running in Tomcat 7.0.5.
1st Project hosts the Services(Web Services) which are used in 2nd Project.
Both Projects has separates Databases but on same Mysql Server Instance.
Technologies used are Spring,Hibernate. Database is Mysql. Server is Apache Tomcat 7.0.5
Initially everthing was working fine.
As More Records(1-2 lakh) were added to Database it started giving OutOfMemoryError Exception and Exception in thread "ajp-9009-AsyncTimeout" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space Errors.
I googled for Errors, according to solutions explained i updated Catalina.bat file as follows

```
set JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
-server -Xms1536m -Xmx1536m
-XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m 
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC"
```

and

```
set CATALINA_OPTS=-server -Xms256m -Xmx1024m
```

But nothing worked for me.
How to get Rid of above Errors..?
Am i doing anything wrong..?
And Also i have an Query, Does an WebService Return Lakhs of Record..?

Comment: For the uninitiated, lakh = 100,000

Answer (score 0):

Without specifics, it's difficult to identify your issues.

I would look at tools like YourKit to profile your app (you can get a free 30 day trial, ISTR) and VisualVM to dig down into your JVM.

*But*, if your webservice takes your 100,000 records, renders them into XML/JSON and sends them out in one request/response, then that's a lot of data to pull from the db, marshall and transmit. I would investigate that design and see if that's the fundamental issue.

Answer (score 0):

As you r using the ORM tool to handle the database relaed operation, you can limit the bulk submit to optimum that will not prevent OutOfMemoryError.

Another possible case, I'm not sure on it. this may occur due to JDBC driver. if possible try to use updated jdbc driver jar.